# Applying range requests to encrypted videos

Tags: node.js, html, encryption, video-streaming

By following this article: [Video stream with Node.js and HTML5](https://medium.com/@daspinola/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6), I was able to successfully implement http range requests.

Assuming a start and end value, stream this video chunk works fine:

```
fs.createReadStream('./video.mp4', { start, end })
    .pipe(res)
```

However, let's say I wanted to decrypt and encrypted video file before serving it over http:

```
fs.createReadStream('./encrypted-video.dat')
    .pipe(createDecipher(algorithem, secret))
    .pipe(res)
```

How can http range requests be handled in this case? The `start` and `end` values apply to the decrypted .mp4 video file not the encrypted video. I need to find a way to apply range requests in this case.

Can a duplex stream be used to apply a range request to the decrypt stream before it's passed to the response?

```
fs.createReadStream('./encrypted-video.dat')
    .pipe(createDecipher(algorithem, secret))
    .pipe(passthrough({start, end})
    .pipe(res)
```

Comment: Ultimately it seems you're approaching the problem from the wrong end. If the data is "encrypted/obfuscated" in any way that differs from it's eventual format, then you can't really ask to start reading from "x bytes" without "de-obfuscating" the entire source. That essentially means "pulling down the entire content" rather than being able to ask a "stream" to "start from here". The "decrypt/de-obfuscate" needs to be done where the "source" is served from, and not the request itself. Typically by an authenticated token on request.

Comment: Search for “common encryption”